# Adding external map link as a layer in Mergin

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, basemap, mergin-maps

I have created a project in QGIS to collect field data using the Input (Mergin) app.
I found this [basemap](https://opencity.in/data/bbmp-street-id-map-ward-198-hemmigepura) through the local municipality that gives me the ward area where I will be collecting the field data.

How do I add this [basemap](https://opencity.in/data/bbmp-street-id-map-ward-198-hemmigepura) in Mergin as a layer in order to collect the necessary field data in Input?

I tried to look it up [here](https://merginmaps.com/docs/gis/settingup_background_map/) and was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the ward areas, there is Download KML link on top:
https://data.citizenmatters.com/Data/Bengaluru-BBMP-Street-ID-Ward-198.kml

You can download the KML and convert it to GeoPackage and then load it in QGIS. There seems to be a bug with loading KML in Input which we will sort out shortly (https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues/2040)

For the basemap, it looks like a Google map. You should be able to add it using XYZ layer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Lutra

Comment: The easiest option was for me to create a new project and add the current QGIS project as a package that incorporated the downloaded Ward area map.